# Auto Update Stats not updating Statistics

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, statistics

Am using `SQL SERVER 2012` I have my `Auto Update Stats` *ON* in my database.

From the below link I learned that, the Auto Update stats will fire for every `SQRT(1000 * Table rows)` change in table rows.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/srgolla/2012/09/04/sql-server-statistics-explained/

I created a table with 1000 records

```
SELECT TOP 500 Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn,
                name
INTO   stst
FROM   sys.objects
```

Creating statistics

```
CREATE STATISTICS rn  
    ON stst (rn)  

CREATE STATISTICS name  
    ON stst (name)
```

Checking the created Statistics

```
DBCC show_statistics('stst', rn)  -- Rows 500 

DBCC show_statistics('stst', name) -- Rows 500
```

As per the formula

```
select SQRT(1000 * 500) -- 707.106781186548
```

So If I add/modify `707.106781186548` records in my table auto update statistics should fire

Add `1000` more records to my table which should be more than enough to fire `auto update stats`

```
INSERT INTO stst(rn,name)
SELECT TOP 1000 Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn,
                a.name
FROM   sys.objects a
```

To fire the `auto update stats`

```
Select * from stst
```

Checking the statistics

```
DBCC show_statistics('stst', rn)  -- Rows 500 

DBCC show_statistics('stst', name) -- Rows 500
```

Unfortunately still the `Rows` is `500` only.

Even after inserting `1000` records into my table which is obviously greater than `707.106781186548` while performing `SELECT` why Auto Update stats didn't fire ? What am I missing here

Comment: You're missing a couple things. The improved calculation is only used in versions prior to 2016 if you have Trace Flag 2371 on. Stats don't update when data is modified, they update after data is modified and a query needs to use them (assuming they've met the modification threshold).

Comment: Also a trivial query (e.g. SELECT * without a WHERE clause) won't trigger a stats update. Try running a query that actually makes the engine do something where the stats might be useful (e.g. Equality or range on the leading key column).

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Thanks for the info on *Trace Flag* never know that..

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Feeling so stupid.. What shall I do now.. Shall I delete the question one of you post an answer so that I can mark it as answered

Comment: Don't feel stupid, I learned something from the answers to your question. And I agree @sp_BlitzErik and/or AaronBertrand should post their answers.

Comment: I'll let @AaronBertrand post his as an answer. He could use the points.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The new calculation is only used if trace flag 2371 is enabled, except on SQL Server 2016 when the context database compatibility level is set to 130, where it is the default behaviour. See Microsoft KB 2754171:

[Controlling Autostat (AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS) behavior in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2754171)

Statistics are not updated when data is modified. A statistics update is triggered when *cost-based* optimization finds that interesting statistics for the query are stale.

The optimizer does not enter cost-based optimization for very simple ("trivial") queries, where a single obvious plan is always optimal. No statistics updates occur in that scenario.

See the Microsoft White Paper [Plan Caching and Recompilation in SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn148262.aspx) by Greg Low.